# Get Json_encode to a different jQuery page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am working on a little project to learn more about JSON, but I am kinda stuck. I did a PHP query to get content from my database and I want to pass that data to a different jQuery page with JSON (optional).

Here is my process.php file:

```
<div id="msg" class="msg">
<?php
    $query = "SELECT id, d_prijs, code, artikelNL FROM artikel"; 
    $json =  array();
    $result= $conn->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json[]= $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
</div>
```

This echo works fine and it gives a result, but I want to pass that result to another page and show it on that page.

Here is my jQuery file:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var mycontent  = $('div.msg').text();
    console.log(mycontent);
  });
 });
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, it doesn't give an error either. Any ideas on how I can improve?

Comment: Where is `div` with `myDiv` class?

Comment: Have you loaded your jquery file in your php file?

Comment: @varun was supposed to be msg, my bad but it still doesnt work

Comment: Try $('div.msg').html();

Comment: Hope your `button` has a `type="button"` attribute set. The page should not refresh! @ICTMitchell

Comment: Does the second snippet exist on a different page than the first one?

Comment: @Pratansyah Yes, at a html file.

Comment: @ICTMitchell Then you can't do that without some sort of data transfering mechanism. Why did you chose to approach it this way rather than fetching the data from database on the second page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make AJAX call to the process.php page. Try the following code:

```
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax( {
            type : 'GET',
            url:'process.php',
            success:function(mycontent) {
                console.log(mycontent);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single page application and when you say page you mean hidden/displayed content, your code should work. But if you have actual pages, this will never work because your source div does not exist in the DOM once you have switched pages